# Can't trigger my controllers action with a date time in the route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, get, asp.net-mvc-controller, html.beginform

Here is my form. If I remove the classdate parameter it works fine, but I can't trigger the controller if I have a date in the routevalues

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", new { classDate = DateTime.Now }, FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQueryWithin" name="location">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Results(string navbarSearchQueryWithin, DateTime classDate)
{
    var viewModel = new YogaSpaceListViewModel
    {
        SearchQuery = navbarSearchQueryWithin
    };
    return View("Search", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Probably because the date separator is a `/`. Change the format to ISO format - `DateTime.Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: I tried that. I'm getting a error that says the parameter is null. Is this the way to pass in a default value of today to the controller?

Comment: I can get it to work if I put the date in a hidden field, but I thought route values would handle it???

Comment: Just tried it using your code and it works fine if the date is formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Then something else must be incorrect because I get a server error saying that the parameter is null.

Comment: I didn't realize that this converts it to a string. So then I have to convert it to a datetime in the controller? Can't I pass a datetime type into the controller?

Comment: Everything your client sends to the server is a 'string'. The model binder converts it to a `DateTime` using the `ValueProviders`. Give me a moment and I'll create a DotNetFiddle for you.

Comment: I'm curious because I have another controller that accepts a datetime parameter and I'm passing in the value like this - @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield form-control" }) where classDate is a DateTime type. And my controller's parameter is a datatime type.

Comment: Yes, but its a textbox so its sending that value as form data, but in your question its adding the value as route values but translating it to a url which is `.../Home/Results/8/10/2015` (but I'm assuming you have a route definition for that action with `.../{classdate}`). Inspect the form tag your generating at see what the value of the `action` attribute is

Comment: And as a side note, your parameter `string navbarSearchQueryWithin` will always be `null` - it needs to be `string location` because that's what the name of the input is. But nowhere in your method do you ever refer to the value of `classdate` so what is it for?